# TypeScript 5.2.2 with Cypress.js

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm using TypeScript in my project and after upgrading to version `5.2.2` I can't run my Cypress e2e tests. Here is my tsconfig.json file content:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/scripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

My cypress.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5020',
        specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts',
    },
});
```

I'm using Cypress in version `13.3.0` and whenever I'm running `cypress run --browser chrome --headless` or `cypress open` I'm getting error:

```
> cypress run --browser chrome --headless


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55721/devtools/browser/14f8fba2-9991-4a01-97ae-aab68abe63ce
Missing baseUrl in compilerOptions. tsconfig-paths will be skipped
Your configFile is invalid: <path_to_repo_here>/cypress.config.ts

It threw an error when required, check the stack trace below:

TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
error TS5110: Option 'module' must be set to 'NodeNext' when option 'moduleResolution' is set to 'NodeNext'.

    at createTSError (/Users/<user>/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.3.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:311:16)
    at reportTSError (/Users/<user>/Library/Caches/Cypress/13.3.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:314:23)
(...rest of stack here)
```

And in ts.config.json both `module` and `moduleResolution` are set to `NodeNext`. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround works temporarily:

in `tsconfig.json` set compiler options as follows:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler"
}
```